# Draw multiple draggable rectangles on image?

Tags: matlab, draggable, draw, drawrect

With the following code, I can easily draw one draggable rectangle on given image.

```
figure; 
imshow('image.png');

h = imrect;
p = wait(h);                                              % get the rect position
rectangle('Position', p, 'LineWidth',2, 'EdgeColor','r'); % draw here
```

[image]

The problem is: **how can I draw multiple draggable rectangles on the image?** And in addition, **the number of the rectangles are not known pre-hand**.

P.S. It will become easier if I already the number of rectangles to draw. For example, if I want to draw 2 rectangels, the following code will work, i.e. just put as many of `wait()`:

```
figure; 
imshow('image.png');

h = imrect;
p = wait(h);                                              % get the rect position
rectangle('Position', p, 'LineWidth',2, 'EdgeColor','r'); % draw here
p2 = wait(h);                                             % get the rect position
rectangle('Position', p2, 'LineWidth',2, 'EdgeColor','r'); % draw here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to wrap the position acquisition in a while loop and add some sort of `uicontrol` to indicate when you're done.  In this case, it's just a pushbutton that deletes the `imrect` handle when you're done.  If the handle is deleted, `h` is no longer valid, so `isvalid` stops the `while` loop.  `~isempty` is used as the last returned value of `p` will be empty.

Note that this code overwrites `p` each time so if you want to record all the positions, not just draw rectangles, you will need to add that in.

```
figure
imshow(I)
h = imrect

uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton', 'String', 'Done',...
        'Position', [20 20 50 20],...
        'Callback', 'delete(h)');

while isvalid(h)
  p = wait(h);          
  if ~isempty(p)                                    
      rectangle('Position', p, 'LineWidth',2, 'EdgeColor','r');
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Any idea on how to migrate `NextFrame` button  to `uicontrol` instead of `Done` because I want to loop through a video and draw on each frame of it?

Comment: P.S. In your solution, `Done` button will show after I draw the first rectangle, any idea for the case when there is no rectangles, i.e. show `Done` button before drawing?

Comment: Initialise the `imrect` with a position, e.g. `h = imrect(gca, [10 10 100 100]);` and it won't wait for user input before proceeding to put the uicontrol on.  For the other - that's a whole 'nother question - but basically you'll need an outer loop which handles saving the annotated images and serving up the next frame (if any).